# ssh'ing into my ubuntu machine from another computer on the same wi-fi access point

Tags: networking, wireless, rsync, lan

I would like to copy some large files (photos & video from a vacation) from a mac to an ubuntu machine, over the home wi-fi router that they're both connected to. I've got sshd set up on the receiver, so I'd like to simply rsync over the files from the sender.

Two questions:

Should it be as simple as typing the following in the mac's Terminal?

> rsync -avz ./vacation_pics 127.0.0.X:~me/

If so, how do I find out the local IP (the "X" above) of my Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 always refer to the machine you're currently working from. However, you don't have to use the IP address. You should be able to use hostname.local. For instance, if your Ubuntu computer is called myubuntubox, then you should be able to connect to it by using `ssh myubuntubox.local`

Comment: for completeness, let's mention that typing `ifconfig` in the terminal on Linux machine will show various info for all network interfaces, including their IP address.